# Select all cells for sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use this macro to automate sorting on excel spreadsheets. The problem is that the spreadsheets have various lengths so the ranges differ. How can I make it so that the cells are adjusted based on the spreadsheets without making changes each time.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AD$130").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3, 4, 19, 20 _
    , 21), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: You can use the same named range on each sheet ... ActiveSheet.Range("RangeName")

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates...`.